# How can I resolve the ambiguity among the functions due to the class inheritance?

Tags: java, inheritance, ambiguous

While creating a simple framework I ran into a problem known as `function ambiguity`.

Error message:

```
reference to FOO is ambiguous
    both method foo(XXX) and foo(YYY) match.
```

The problem arose due to simple class inheritance and a complete simplified example is presented through the following code block:

```
import java.util.function.BiFunction;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.JUnit4;

@RunWith(JUnit4.class)
public final class InheritanceDemoTest {

  class A {}

  class B extends A {}

  static void foo(A a1, A a2, BiFunction<A, A, String> f) {}

  static void foo(A a1, B b2, BiFunction<A, B, String> f) {}

  @Test
  public void f() {
    A a = null;
    B b = null;
    foo(a, b, (c, d) -> "");
  }
}
```

Error message:

```
reference to foo is ambiguous
    foo(a, b, (c, d) -> "");
both method foo(InheritanceDemoTest.A,InheritanceDemoTest.A,BiFunction<InheritanceDemoTest.A,InheritanceDemoTest.A,String>) in InheritanceDemoTest and method foo(InheritanceDemoTest.A,InheritanceDemoTest.B,BiFunction<InheritanceDemoTest.A,InheritanceDemoTest.B,String>) in InheritanceDemoTest match
```

I must admit that I did not expect this behavior of the compiler and that I don't understand how the compiler actually works. My expectation was that the compiler would always choose the best possible match - that is, the function closest in inheritance level to the passed arguments.

What are the best techniques I could use to overcome this problem?

I used different names for ambiguous functions - the complete code worked however the framework became ugly and difficult to use

Comment: What should happen if you call `foo(b, b, …)`?

Comment: Do functions need to be static?

Comment: I think you should be able to explicitly cast the `b` argument to a specific type: `foo(a, (A) b, (c, d) -> "");` or `foo(a, (B) b, (c, d) -> "");`

Comment: Type the parameters of the lambda: `foo(a, b, (A c, B d) -> "");` [`Ideone.com` demo](https://ideone.com/TGLjNY)

Comment: @QBrute sadly, this does not work. `b` is already of static type `B`, the cast will do nothing. [`Ideone.com` demo](https://ideone.com/hvuxFq)

Comment: Different behaviour in inherited classes would best be expressed by a method that is overwritten in the inherited class. So an elegant solution would be to move the behaviour of `foo` into the class `A` and then provide a different implementation of `foo` in `B`.